# Why does std::stack not use template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Why do `std::stack` and `std::queue` use type template parameter instead of template template parameter for their underlying container type?

i.e. why is `stack` declared like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Container = deque<T>>
class stack;
```

but not like this:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Container = deque>
class stack;
```

?

Comment: @CoryKramer this question is not a duplicate of the linked question: The linked question asks about where to we need to put template/typename, while this question is about why an existing class (`deque`) has a certain interface, not about a syntactic question.

Comment: Do defaults even work for template template parameters?

Comment: @anatolyg Yes, they work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because typically containers like [`std::vector` have more than one template argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). By not caring about it being a template, you allow every kind of container to be used.

How would

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector;
```

fit onto

```
template<typename> class Container
```

as you would have it in your `stack`? (Hint: it doesn't!) You'd need special cases for each number and kind of template arguments (type vs. non-type) you'd want to support, which is silly, because these typically don't contribute any more information than a simple

```
typename Container
```

Note that to get at the actual template arguments of e.g. a `std::vector`, you have the typedefs `std::vector::value_type` and `std::vector::allocator_type`, removing the need of having these types available explicitly where you actually use the type (i.e. the `Container` of `stack`).

Comment: Ouch. I thought it would be more convenient to be able to write `std::stack<T, std::vector>` without specifying T twice, but didn't think about restrictions on container template parameters.

Comment: @Hedede Think also about containers which aren't even instantiated from templates. With your design you couldn't do something like `std::stack<double, MySpecialContainerWhichOnlyWorksForDoubles>`.

Comment: It's far worse than "special cases of each _number_ of template aguments", because the template template parameter might have a mix of type and non-type template arguments. I.e. not only could you have `Container<Type1, Type2>` but also `Container<Type1, Int2>`. That makes it _exponentially_ worse.

Answer (score 20):

**In short:** Because using a template template parameter is more restrictive* than using a type parameter without providing any advantages.

<sub>* By **restrictive** I mean that you may need a more complex stuff to obtain the same results than with a "simple" type parameter.</sub>

**Why is there no advantages?**

Your `std::stack` probably has an attribute like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Container>
struct stack {
    Container container;
};
```

If you replace `Container`, by a template template parameter, why would you obtain?

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Container>
struct stack {
    Container<T> container;
};
```

You are instantiating `Container` only once and only for `T` (`Container<T>`), so there is **no advantages** for a template template parameter.

**Why is it more restrictive?**

With a template template parameter, you have to pass to `std::stack` a template which expose the same signature, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class Container>
struct stack;

stack<int, std::vector> // Error: std::vector takes two template arguments
```

Maybe you could use variadic templates:

```
template <typename T, template <typename... > class Container>
struct stack {
    Container<T> container;
};

stack<int, std::vector> // Ok, will use std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>
```

But what if I do not want to use the standard `std::allocator<int>`?

```
template <typename T, 
          template <typename....> class Container = std::vector, 
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
struct stack {
    Container<T, Allocator> container;
};

stack<int, std::vector, MyAllocator> // Ok...
```

This is becoming a bit messy... What if I want to use my own container templates that takes 3/4/N parameters?

```
template <typename T,
          template <typename... > class Container = std::vector,
          typename... Args>
struct stack {
    Container<T, Args...> container;
};

stack<int, MyTemplate, MyParam1, MyParam2> // Ok...
```

But, what if I want to use a non-templated containers?

```
struct foo { };
struct foo_container{ };

stack<foo, foo_container> // Error!

template <typename... >
using foo_container_template = foo_container;

stack<foo, foo_container_template> // Ok...
```

With a type parameter there are no such issues<sup>1</sup>:

```
stack<int>
stack<int, std::vector<int, MyAllocator<int>>
stack<int, MyTemplate<int, MyParam1, MyParam2>>
stack<foo, foo_container>
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> There are other cases which do not work with template template parameter such as using templates accepting a mix of type and non-type parameters in specific orders, for which you can create generic template template parameter, even using variadic templates.</sub>

Comment: I don’t think this is the correct answer at all: see the other answers for a correct reason.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In c++11, you could use `template <typename... > class Container` and it would work with a template template parameter.

Comment: @Holt True, fair enough. That said, the interface of course predates C++11, and the *reason* for the interface design is first and foremost the technical restriction of pre-11 C++.

Comment: @Holt But if you use a variadic template template, you still need to get the arguments somehow, so you'd then need variadic parameters on `std::stack` to fill in the arguments to the container.

Comment: @TartanLlama Not if the arguments are defaulted in the given template.

Comment: @Holt what if your container takes no template arguments?

Comment: @nate Like `foo_container` at the end of my answer?

Comment: @Hold lol, didn't see that, just saw argument for variadic template arguments in these comments.

Comment: I suppose a follow-up question I have is: "in that case, what's a good way to enforce that the chosen container type actually stores values of type `T`?", seeing as this is one thing that would be guaranteed if the `template template` approach were used... I guess C++20 concepts fit this bill..? One could have a `Storey<T>` concept for types that store `T`s...

Answer (score 18):

Using a template template parameter would restrict the types that you could use as the underlying container to those that expose the same template signature. This form allows arbitrary types as long as they support the expected interface.

Answer (score 13):

[Because it doesn’t compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2f7a8cdfa7ffa97):

`std::deque` isn’t of type

```
template <typename T> class std::deque
```

it’s of type

```
template<class T, class Alloc> class std::deque
```

This of course is a more general problem: even if we were to provide the `Alloc` template parameter to our `stack` class template, the class would now only work with containers that have exactly two type template arguments. This is an unreasonable restriction.

Comment: @Holt here had a nice answer about type-parameter allowing to use non-template containers like `struct foo; struct foo_container; using foo_stack = std::stack<foo, foo_container>`. But when talking about modern standards, would `template<typename...>` allow the use of such containers? i.e., can the variadic template "reduce" to a simple class with no template parameters?

Comment: @Artalus Good question. No, it can’t. His answer’s back up, by the way.